# CSS3 Responsive popup

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create a search box with a results popup that looks good on both desktop and mobile.

I'll try to explain better using these two mock-ups:
[image: Desktop version of search box][image: Mobile version of search box]

For the desktop version, I'd like to specify a width and height for the results popup and have it float over the page content.

For the mobile version, the results fill the entire screen width and the entire height below the search box. So no content peeks out behind it, and no scrolling to see any part of the search results.

Conceptually, I reckon I need a media query for this, but I'm struggling to get it to work well.

I've included a full snippet, but here's the CSS that I tinkered with. The value of `320px` is completely arbitrary and that's part of my problem.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .popup {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .popup {
    width: 295px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 320px) {
  .popup {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 320px) {
  .popup {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

There are two things that bug me:

1. Looking at these min- and max-width values doesn't really work so well. A full HD phone will appear to be a desktop PC, despite being only 5 inch in size. Is there a pure CSS way to limit to screen size instead of resolution? Or to both, which would then also cater for resized desktop browsers.
2. Making the width 100% works fine, because my popup starts at the very left of the screen. A height of 100% doesn't work, because the total height is then 100% of the screen + search box height + logo height (once I add that) and it therefore scrolls off the bottom of the screen. What I need is a way to size it to distance between the top of my `DIV` and the bottom of the screen.

I wouldn't mind a JavaScript solution, but I think I should be able to do this with only CSS and would prefer that.

Also, I'm happy with a solution that is only compatible with newer browsers (say two years old max).

**Edit:**
I should add that I'm using Foundation in the project. I didn't use anything from Foundation in this snippet, but if there is something useful I missed, I'm more than happy to use it.

```css
input {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.popup {
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: Green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .popup {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .popup {
    width: 295px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 320px) {
  .popup {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 320px) {
  .popup {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input/>
<div class="popup">
</div>
<div>
  Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. Some random text that is supposed to wind up underneath the popup. 
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: for mobile, `height:100vh`

Comment: Why would a HD phone appear as a desktop PC with a max-width media query?

Comment: Also, your media queries are so over-complicated. What you're trying to achieve is simple and your media queries should match that simplicity.

Comment: @Tom I just meant that screen resolution alone doesn't distinguish between large and small screen devices. A standard 1366x768 laptop has a lower resolution than an HD phone.

Comment: @Tom Too complicated? Jack's answer seems similarly complex to me. How would you go about simplifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's possible to include resolution (pixel density) in a media query to target things like retina or HD phones. For example,

`@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi)`

will target various retina and HiDPI devices. ([Source](https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599).) You can combine this with size queries if needed.

2) To get something that's "screen-height", try using `100vh` instead of `100%`. `vh` means `viewport height unit`; `100vh` = 1 window height. (`50vh` = half a window height, etc. `vw` does the same thing for widths.) If you find that's still too tall, you may need to tweak it to subtract whatever's adding height - IE, if you've got a logo or whatever that's pushing the 100vh element down by 80px, you'd change the height to `height: calc(100vh - 80px)` to make it fit.

Comment: I ended up only looking at size, because there is even more confusion when looking at the pixel ratio. But this is the correct answer to my question.